# What algorithm is used to select a voxel (from a player's perspective)?

Tags: 3d, voxels, mouse, interface

In first-person voxel games (like Minecraft, shown below) you can select voxels by going over them. What kind of algorithm is used to select a voxel?

[image: Minecraft]

I haven't implemented it in my voxel application yet, but the only solution I could think of would be casting a ray and checking for intersections but it seems very inefficient.

Comment: `casting a ray and checking for intersections but it seems very inefficient.` thats exactly what minecraft does.

Comment: You should also limit the voxels you check by eliminating voxels out of your character's "reach". So if your character can only use voxels for up to 4 steps away you just need to check the voxels surrounding him in 4 units in every direction.You can further reduce the voxels you check by only searching voxels in front of your player's view.

Comment: Some engines can even use raycasts to render the whole scene, using octrees to speed things up. Resulting in a raytracer renderer. So raycasts are actually quite darn fast if optimized well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Raycasting is what you want. As far as I know Minecraft uses raycasting aswell. How it works is basicly, that you send a "ray", represented as a 3D vector from the middle of your camera. The voxel you look at then is the first one the ray "
collides with.
ThinMatrix made a [tutorial on ray casting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLKN0jExRIM).

Comment: Just dont convert the mouse position to a 3D vector. Instead use the coordinates of your crosshair!

Comment: Could you please make the answer more standalone. Link-only answers inevitably are rendered useless by servers and pages going away.